# MySQL Workbench Charset wrong

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image]

Any idea how to fix this char set problem?

MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Perhaps it is CHARACTER SET ucs2.  Where did the data come from?

Answer (score 0):

If the second column is `idAccount`, then the source of the data, including the column headers, seems to be in `CHARACTER SET ucs2`.

Perhaps Excel?

See if you can get export in "UTF-8".